# Testing DELETE using spring-test-mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, junit, tdd, spring-test-mvc

I am using Spring MVC to create RESTful endpoints. I am using spring-test-mvc to test them at the unit/integration test level. I am now coming across this team's first attempt at implementing an endpoint using DELETE. This means the container needs to be setup to allow for DELETE (PUT will come shortly after). My research took me here:

http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html

I am technically using JBoss, but I have a feeling a Tomcat write-up will do just fine. Anyway, my problem is not at the container level.

I am trying to create a unit test to verify the most basic of 404. Let's say you try to delete a user calling /users/{id}. My test passes an invalid id, and I expect a 404 to return. It gives a 405. This makes sense when DELETE is not supported. Following the instructions in the link above, I should add some entries to the web.xml. I did so in main and test. Both still gave me the 405.

How would I setup spring-test-mvc to grab these new http-method types out of the web.xml or some other location? My research hasn't come up with anything other than DELETE isn't initially supported.

Thanks
Dustin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-test-mvc does support DELETE(and PUT), I have used it with a DELETE based method, it is true that you need to add `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` filter in `web.xml` for DELETE http method to work within your application, however spring-test-mvc does not look at the filter, it works from `DispatcherServlet` down, here is one of the samples that works for me:

```
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/members/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The error you are seeing I feel could be more related to the `content-type` or `accept headers`, that is where I have seen 405 being returned, you may be able to change your log level to debug or trace and see what else shows up.

Comment: I hate when you are right. It ended up being related to the various mappings. Good to know I didn't need to fuss with the web.xml initially. Thanks.